# specify screen size of avd in windows command line

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I start avd command line, by defaults it starts with a very big screen (more than 10in)and takes ages to load. But starting it from the SDK manager it works just fine with the screen size I want eg. 4in.

How do I specify this screen size from command line? I'm using the following command

```
emulator -avd SamsungGalaxy -partition-size 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-scale <scale>` or `-dpi-device <dpi>` options.

The `-scale` option will scale the emulator window based on the factor 
(`<scale>` is number between 0.1 and 3; or a dpi value, i.e. `96dpi`) 
that you specify as an argument to the option.

The `-dpi-device` scales the resolution to match the screen size of a physical device. 
The default value is 165.

For instance, for your specific case you may initialize the emulator as follows:

```
emulator -avd SamsungGalaxy -scale 96dpi -dpi-device 160 -partition-size 100
```

To check all the available emulator options, you should check this reference: [Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#startup-options).

There's also a link that explains how to support multiple screens: [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support)

I hope this helps.

Comment: `-scale` is now deprecated https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#deprecated